# ng-click is not working when passing function into directive

Tags: angularjs

I try to store menu information in an array(`menu_entries` in the example) and render them with a directive(`myMenu`), but the functions stored in the array seem not to work with ng-click.

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/5CaQx/

menu1 and menu2 are not working, but menu3 works.

JS code:

```
  var my_app;

  my_app = angular.module('myApp', []);

  my_app.controller('myPageCtrl', [
    '$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.menu_entries = [
        {
          name: 'menu1',
          onclick: $scope.onMenu1Click
        }, {
          name: 'menu2',
          onclick: $scope.onMenu2Click
        }
      ];
      $scope.say_something = "";
      $scope.onMenu1Click = function() {
        return $scope.say_something = "lalala";
      };
      $scope.onMenu2Click = function() {
        return $scope.say_something = "wawawa";
      };
      return $scope.onMenu3Click = function() {
        return $scope.say_something = "rarara";
      };
    }
  ]);

  my_app.directive("myMenu", [
    "$compile", function($compile) {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
          menue: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
          elem.html('<div ng-repeat="me in menue"><li><div class="menu-btn" ng-click="me.onclick()"><div class="menu-text">{{me.name}}</div></div></li></div>');
          return $compile(elem.contents())(scope);
        }
      };
    }
  ]);
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="../css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myPageCtrl">
      <p>
        {{say_something}}
      </p>
      <ul>
        <my_menu menue="menu_entries"></my_menu>
        <li>
          <div class="menu-btn" ng-click="onMenu3Click()">
            <div class="menu-text">
              menu3
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$scope.onMenu1Click = function() {
        return $scope.say_something = "lalala";
      };
      $scope.onMenu2Click = function() {
        return $scope.say_something = "wawawa";
      };
      //Move this code after the creating $scope.onMenu1Click and $scope.onMenu2Click
      $scope.menu_entries = [
        {
          name: 'menu1',
          onclick: $scope.onMenu1Click //onMenu1Click  instead of menu1Click 
        }, {
          name: 'menu2',
          onclick: $scope.onMenu2Click //onMenu2Click  instead of menu2Click 
        }
      ];
```

[Update fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8Y9R/)

Comment: Sorry for the typo, but the key is the function declaration order. Thank for your help!!